# How to clear Google Places Autocomplete component that is nested in Formik form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, formik, google-places

I am working with a Formik form with several fields, and I have a Google Places Autocomplete component from the "react-native-google-places-autocomplete" library. Everything submits correctly to Firebase, and all the input fields clear. However, the Google Places Autocomplete input does not clear. How can I have the input clear here? Note that the value of the input is reset when the form is submitted, but the displayed text does not.

**Google Places Autocomplete Component**

```
<GooglePlacesAutocomplete
        renderLeftButton={() => (
          <Icon
            name="location"
            type="evilicon"
            color={colors.middlegray}
            style={styles.icon}
          />
        )}
        placeholder="Where is it?"
        textInputProps={{
          placeholderTextColor: colors.lightgray,
        }}
        styles={toInputBoxStyles}
        onBlur={() => setFieldTouched("location")}
        returnKeyType={"search"}
        fetchDetails={true}
        name="location"
        enablePoweredByContainer={false}
        nearbyPlacesAPI="GooglePlacesSearch"
        debounce={400}
        value={searchWords.searchKeyword}
        query={{
          key: GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY,
          language: "en",
        }}
        onPress={(data, details = null) => {
          const max = 10000000;
          const min = 1;
          const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
          setSearch({ searchKeyword: data.description });
          setFieldValue("location", details.name);
          setFieldValue("latitude", details.geometry.location.lat);
          setFieldValue("longitude", details.geometry.location.lng);
          setFieldValue("selectionID", random);
        }}
      />
      <ErrorMessage error={errors["location"]} visible={touched["location"]} />
    </>
```

**Screen with Formik Form**

```
<Screen style={styles.container}>
      <AppText style={styles.title}>Upload a plan idea</AppText>
      <AppText style={styles.subtitle}>Not anonymous</AppText>
      <KeyboardAwareScrollView
        style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"
      >
        {/** AppForm (components>forms) */}
        <AppForm
          // sets initial values, or the fields that must be filled out
          initialValues={{
            title: "",
            price: "",
            location: "",
            mood: null,
            images: [],
            selectionID: 0,
          }}
          onSubmit={handleSubmit}
          // sets validation rules that must be followed to upload
          validationSchema={validationSchema}
        >
          {/** FormImagePicker (components>forms) NOT WORKING */}
          <View style={tailwind("py-5")}>
            <FormImagePicker name="images" />
          </View>
          {/** AppFormField: (components>forms) */}
          {/** name property in the field is what sets the field equal to the value */}
          <AppText style={styles.text}>Title</AppText>
          <AppFormField
            maxLength={255}
            icon="lightbulb-on-outline"
            name="title"
            placeholder="What is your idea?"
          />
          <AppText style={styles.text}>Price</AppText>
          <AppFormField
            icon="currency-usd"
            keyboardType="numeric"
            maxLength={3}
            name="price"
            placeholder="How much will it cost?"
          />
          <View style={tailwind("flex-row items-center")}>
            <AppText style={styles.text}>Location </AppText>
            <AppText style={{ fontSize: 10, color: colors.gray }}>
              (from dropdown)
            </AppText>
          </View>
          <View style={tailwind("py-2")}>
            <GooglePlaceAutocomplete />
          </View>
          <AppText style={styles.text}>Mood</AppText>
          {/** AppFormPicker (components>forms) */}
          <AppFormPicker
            items={moods}
            icon="emoticon-outline"
            name="mood"
            numberOfColumns={3}
            // specify type of pickeritemcomponent
            PickerItemComponent={CategoryPickerItem}
            placeholder="What's the mood?"
            width="100%"
          />
          <SubmitButton title="Post" />
        </AppForm>
      </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
    </Screen>
```

**Functions that Handle OnSubmit**

```
  // create function to handle submit and posting
  const handleSubmit = async (event, { resetForm }) => {
    const imageUris = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < event.images.length; index++) {
      console.log("here");
      const uploadUrl = await uploadImageAsync(
        event.images[index],
        event.title,
        index
      );
      imageUris.push(uploadUrl);
    }
    // pass in database you got from the firebase file; users collection, sending user info for uid
    await addDoc(collection(db, "users", user.uid, "likedEvents"), {
      images: imageUris,
      postedById: user.uid,
      postedBy: user.displayName,
      title: event.title,
      price: event.price,
      location: [event.location, event.longitude, event.latitude],
      mood: event.mood.label,
      selectionID: event.selectionID,
      // hoursOfOperation: event.hoursOfOperation,
      // website: event.website,
      // googlePrice: event.googlePrice,
      createdOn: serverTimestamp(),
      likes: 0,
      likes_by_users: [],
      // do not use own timestamps due to time zones
    })
      .catch((error) => {
        Alert.alert(error.message);
      })
      .then(Alert.alert("Upload Succesful"));

    // resets form internally, not fully visually
    resetForm();
  };
```